# How to call Android method from AngularJS directive?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, typescript

I have html which is using Angularjs directive, this html file is used in Android WebView and I would like to call Android method from this directive ([How to call Android method from JS](http://saifo.blogspot.de/2013/07/calling-activity-method-from-javascript.html))

Here is my directive,

```
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('controller.isReady', function (value) {
                if (value === true) {
                    try {
                        Android.isReady();
                    } catch (e) {}
                }
            });  
        }
    }
```

As I am using Typescript, obviously I am getting an error saying that `Android` is undefined. Even if there will be pure AngularJS, the `Android` object would be still undefined.

Is there a way to make this work, so that I will be able to call Android method from AngularJs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to [declare](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2013/07/22/quick-tip-typescript-declare-keyword/) the `Android` object.

```
interface AndroidApi {
    isReady(): void;
}

declare var Android: AndroidApi;
```

Then `Android.isReady()` will make sense to the compiler.

---

#### Edit

This is a better resource for [ambient declarations](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/intro.html).

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Although this solves the problem with compilation, however it seems that in this way it kind-of creates a new object and overrides the defined `Android` object in android native code, so that in android app actually the method isn't called..Although seems that `declare` shouldn't do that?

Comment: @vtorosyan That shouldn't happen. The `declare` statement doesn't get included in the javascript output of the compiler. Check that this is indeed the case with your js file.